# Order by Even/Odd on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have to do a query with three types of order:

```
ORDER BY pinned DESC, trending DESC, distance ASC
```

But I want to display the list of items like this:

- Pinned Item.
- Trending Item.
- Closest Item (order by distance).
- Pinned Item.
- Trending Item.
- Closest Item.
- Etc.

Like this:

[image]

As you can see, currently the first one is "Pinned" (0 or 1), the second one is "Trending Item" (0 or 1), an then the distance, is not a column, is calculated from the lat and lng.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.  I don't see how this works with three separate columns.  What if an item is pinned and trending?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gordon Linoff, take a look again. Doesn't matter if an item is pinned and trending, they can be ordered even ramdonly Regards.

Comment: But what is the problem? You can sort by a calculated column.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I wanna merge that, right now the order is: first the pinned, then the trending, and the others by calculated column "distance". I want to order: pinned, trending, distance, pinned, trending, distance, etc... Or even random.